Windows Server doesnt start: Error: 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
All, who can help me?
i created a new service with succes. but when i want to start the service i get the error: Error: 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
its looking for a .bat file.
Attach the file. who can help me with this issue?
NSSM is not an option for me.
thanks
enter image description here
enter image description here
also added new regedit: ServicesPipeTimeout
